# Use Velocity to generate HTML based email

Tags: java, css, velocity

I try this tutorials http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Velocity/UseVelocitytogenerateHTMLbasedemail.htm
but, when i add css, it look like not executed.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <TITLE>Pet Store Sale!</TITLE>
  <style type="text/css">
    body    {
            margin: 0 0 0 0;
            padding: 0 0 0 0;
            text-align: center; 
            background-color: #FFF;
            border-top: 3px solid #CCC;
            }


    #container  {
                position: relative;
                width: 860px;
                height: 1600px;
                margin: 84 auto 0 auto;
                padding: 0 0 0 0;
                background-color: #FFF;
                }


    p       {
            font-family: times, Times New Roman, times-roman, georgia, serif;
            color: #444;
            margin: 0 0 0 0;
            padding: 0 0 0 0;
            text-align: center;
            }


    .woodtwo        {
                    font-size: 22px;
                    line-height: 46px;
                    letter-spacing: -1px;
                    }


    .eyebrow        {   
                    font-size: 19px;
                    line-height: 29px;
                    }


    .caps           {
                    font-size: 14px;
                    line-height: 20px;
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    }


    .copyone        {
                    font-size: 16px;
                    line-height: 20px;
                    }


    #line           {
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
                    width: 748px;
                    margin: 10 0 20 56;
                    }



    #break          {
                    height: 30px;
                    }


    a:link          { color: #B95E27; text-decoration: none; } 
    a:visited       { color: #B95E27; text-decoration: none; }
    a:active        { color: #1A69A1; text-decoration: none; } 
    a:hover         { color: #888; text-decoration: none;}


    .grey           { color: #888; }


    .smallcaps      { font-size: 88%; }


</style>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<div id="container">
    <p class="caps"><a href="">From Pet Store Sale</a></p>
    <div id="line"></div>
    <p class="eyebrow">
        <span class="grey">*</span>T<span class="smallcaps">HANK YOU FOR JOINING </span>P<span class="smallcaps">ET</span> S<span class="smallcaps">TORE</span> S<span class="smallcaps">ALE</span> A<span class="smallcaps">PPLICATION</span><span class="grey">*</span>
    </p>
    <p class="copyone">
        <i>You received this email because your registration process in Pet Store Sale is successful.<br/>
        To Confirm your registration, please visit this link <a href ="$link">Confirmation Link</a>.<br/>
        Your username : $username<br/>
        Password : $password<br/>
        If you have any questions about Application, please send an email to <a href="mailto:admin@store.com">admin@store.com</a></i> 
        <br><br><b>THANK YOU</b>
    </p>
    <div id="break"></div>

    <p class="woodtwo">
        <a href="">GETTING STARTED</a>
    <div id="line"></div>
    <div id="line"></div>
</div>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

i've also tried

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/css/emailFormat.css" type="text/css"  media="screen" />
```

but it not work too.
how the right way to add css on to this page. Thank you

Comment: Also, I just noticed, but using a relative path to a CSS in an e-mail sounds like something that will not work. Either embed the CSS or publish it and make a reference to that published resource.

Comment: if you mean this?
'</head>
<body >

 <div id="container">
  <p class="caps"><a href="">From Testing Application</a></p>
  <div id="line"></div>
  <p class="eyebrow">
   <span class="grey">*</span>T<span class="smallcaps">HANK YOU FOR JOINING </span>T<span class="smallcaps">ESTING</span> M<span class="smallcaps">ONITORING</span> A<span class="smallcaps">PPLICATION</span><span class="grey">*</span>
  </p>
  <p class="copyone">
..........................'

Comment: so, how to send email in html format. i want to send a pretty email in java.

Comment: Edit your question and add the velocity template in it. Comments are too small and not suited for code. For the pretty e-mail, have a look at my previous comment. Either embedd your CSS in some `<style>` tags in your HTML code or reference a public CSS with an absolute URL.

Comment: i've edit the question, hopefully in accordance with your request

Answer (score 16, accepted):

CSS classes are ignored by email clients. If you are using standalone clients like Outlook Express, `div`s will also not be recognized (dont depend on `float:left`).

I suggest you to change your HTML page like -

1. Drop everything outside the `<body>...</body>`
2. Use `<table>` instead of `<div>`
3. Dont use `<style>` tags to define style-classes, or .css file to load styles. Instead use inline css like `style="...."` inside  the `<td>` / `<table>` containers.

Hope this helps you in email template designing.

Comment: whether all the pretty emails that I received are made in this way?

Comment: these are ethics of building email templates, which will be working in all email-websites (like gmail.com) and stand-alone clients (like outlook express). but that does not mean every emails you receive follows this.

Comment: do you know a way to automatically make this changes?

Comment: I used Apache Velocity and also discovered that it didn't take into account the table styles declared in the head section of the template. So the solution that worked was to use inline styles on every th, td, table element. Velocity added `x_` prefix to my `.custom_table` class when generating a template. Crazy, agreed? That 's why I don't like it.