# How to insert for statement in java email message

Tags: java, html, email, servlets

I created a html page with append rows dynamically.
I created an array of strings to get the values into the servlet.
And now, I am trying to send an email to myself with all these values.
For that i am using java mail API in my servlet.
How can i give the string of arrays in the 
message.setText();

If it is not possible, what are the different ways to send email with array of strings.

```
String[] items = request.getParameterValues("Item");
    String[] categories = request.getParameterValues("Category");
    String[] names = request.getParameterValues("Name");
    String[] quantities = request.getParameterValues("Quantity");

    System.out.println("************ExperimentServlet************");

    for (String item : items) {
    System.out.println("Item is : "+item);
    }

    for(String category : categories) {
    System.out.println("Category is : "+category);
    }

    for(String name : names) {
    System.out.println("Name is : "+name);
    }

    for(String quantity : quantities) {
    System.out.println("Quantity is : "+quantity);
    }


    for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {
        System.out.println("Item 1 is :" + items[i]);
        System.out.println("Category 1 is :"+ categories[i]);
        System.out.println("Name 1 is :"+ names[i]);
        System.out.println("Quantity 1 is : "+quantities[i]);

    }

Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("abcdef@gmail.com", "xyz");
                }
            });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("abcdef@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("jklm@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("My eMail First Example");
        message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!"
           + "\n\n" + items[i] + "  " + categories[i]+ "    "+ names[i]+ "  "+ quantities[i]


                );

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

}

If i do this, i am able to send the email with values less than 20 set of values but the thing is it is showing array index out of bounds exception if i supply less than 20 set of values. There is no guarantee that each user supply 20 set of values.

Comment: Whats wrong with preparing a String from that array ? Iterate over array and prepare a String.

Comment: Sends a CSV file (attactment) with the required data and you can forget about the HTML message (only if you want).

Comment: @PaulVargas not all end users feel good to open and parse a csv for reading emails =\

Comment: I created String[]. To create String from that array, i need to use for statement. I am unable to use for statement in message.setText().

Comment: @Devi is that setText()  method not taking a String as a argument ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ it is taking a String but not taking String[].

Comment: @devi please  look here and prepare a string from  your array and pass it to that method : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925420/how-to-create-a-string-from-string-array-or-arraylist

Comment: Even this is also working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following example sites, that could help you

http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/velocity-email-template.html

http://www.vogella.com/articles/FreeMarker/article.html

Comment: I can't give strings directly like this. As i am appending the rows in HTML page, how can i know that how many set of values are supplied by the user. So, i can't do it. I posted my code, just go through once.

Comment: Is that the case, then use Velocity or freemarker that could help you.

Answer (score 1):

There are no loops in HTML.

You should use a templating solution like Velocity to generate the email body by looping over dynamic data and then sending the result.

[Use Velocity to generate HTML based email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296667/use-velocity-to-generate-html-based-email)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ the Servlet is not the right place to generate the HTML content for the email. It will be better for maintenance reasons to use an HTML template using velocity or another library. Remember that in MVC, the view logic must be in the view, in this case, in the email HTML generator, while the Servlet is the controller that just collect the data to be used in the view.

Comment: I gave an answer, you did not.  I have no idea what you're thinking.  I sometimes misread questions by going too fast, so it could be me.